# Fetch datatype of salesforce field

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, salesforce

I integrated salesforce with asp.net using SOAP API.
How to fetch the field datatype of salesforce in asp.net c# program.

Thanks,
Rajeshkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [describeSObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm)(s) call returns all the metadata about an object and its fields, include the field type.

Comment: It works fine.It fetch the entire field from salesforce. Can you please help me how to fetch particular fields from salesforce.

Comment: It will be more better if there is any option to fetch only custom fields in the object.